# How to check row is a sub-row of specified rows in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I want to check whether row in data frame (pandas) is a sub-row of a specified row. All columns have True/False values.
e.g: specified row is 11010 with 5 columns and the sub-row is 10000, the 11110 is not. Clearly, sub-row only contain True values if and only if father-row has True values at corresponding columns.
I have a data frame below:

```
    A   B     C      D    E 
1 True False True False False 
2 True False False True False
3 True True False False True
```

Input row: specified row `True False True True True`
Expected output is the first and second row
Thanks for help!

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Can you put an example with expected output?

Comment: I have a data frame below:
    A                     B                C                 D                E
1  True             False           True            False           False
2   True            False            False          True            Flase

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: @TrầnLêPhương please add your example in the post instead of comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose `df` is your DataFrame and `row` is the input row as a Series:

```
row = pd.Series([True, False, True, True, True], index=df.columns)
```

You are to find the rows in `df` that do not dominate `row` in any column:

```
answer_index = (df <= row).all(axis=1)
df[answer_index]
#      A      B      C      D      E
#1  True  False   True  False  False
#2  True  False  False   True  False
```